# Solspace Calendar ICS for single event

Tags: solspace

Is it possible to have an .ics file to download a single event in a calendar?  right now downloading the .ics downloads the entire calendar

```
{exp:calendar:icalendar
event_id="{segment_3}" dynamic="on"
{/exp:calendar:icalendar}
```

I figured something like the above would only export the one event using the dynamic on and event id but it downloads the entire calendar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well..

https://solspace.com/docs/calendar/icalendar/

> All of the parameters listed in Calendar:Events are available for use here.

and then..

https://solspace.com/docs/calendar/events/#event_id

Have you tried hard coding a known (and **open**) event_id?

Comment: my code eventually worked had some segment issues